# The data structure of multiple fields in Lucene

Tags: lucene

If I have one document with two fields title and content, the data as: title is: Java Book, content is: Java book is selling. What will the inverted index structure looks like, I mean it would be one inverted index which store the fields in doc object in posting table,like:

```
java doc1(title,content)
book doc1(title,content)
selling doc1(content)
```

Or there would be two inverted indexes representing different fields:

```
Field title: 
java doc1
book doc1

Field content:
java doc1
book doc1
selling doc1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lucene term (an indexed element) consists of two parts: a field name and value. So in you case it will be one inverted index and will be look like this:

```
title:java -> doc1
title:book -> doc1
content:java -> doc1
content:book -> doc1
content:selling -> doc1
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, could you please provide some documents(url) to prove your point.

Comment: You can read about file format at this url https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/fileformats.html#Inverted%20Indexing